# What is the allocation being saved here?

Tags: c#, .net

In "Getting Started with Asynchronous Programming in .NET" by Filip Ekberg, in the "Asynchronous Programming Deep Dive/Working with Attached and Detached Tasks" chapter, he says that by using the `service` value inside the async anonymous method, **it introduces a closure and unnecessary allocation**:

> [image]

Next, he says it's better to pass `services` as a parameter to the action delegate of the `StartNew` method **which avoids unnecessary allocations by avoiding a closure**:

> [image]

**My question is:**
**What is the allocation the author says it's being saved by passing the `services` as parameter?**

To make it easier to investigate, I took a much simpler example and put it in the `sharplab.io`:

1. Not passing the parameter:

   ```cs
   using System;

   public class C {
       public void M() {
           var i = 1;     
           Func<int> f = () => i + 1;
           f();
       }
   }
   ```

   which compiles to:

   ```cs
   public class C
   {
       [CompilerGenerated]
       private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
       {
           public int i;

           internal int <M>b__0()
           {
               return i + 1;
           }
       }

       public void M()
       {
           <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
           <>c__DisplayClass0_.i = 1;
           new Func<int>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>b__0)();
       }
   }
   ```

   There are two allocations, one for the generated class and one for the `Func<int>` delegate.
2. Passing the parameter:

   ```cs
   using System;

   public class C {
       public void M() {
           var i = 1;        
           Func<int, int> f = (x) => x + 1;
           f(i);
       }
   }
   ```

   which compiles to:

   ```cs
   public class C
   {
       [Serializable]
       [CompilerGenerated]
       private sealed class <>c
       {
           public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

           public static Func<int, int> <>9__0_0;

           internal int <M>b__0_0(int x)
           {
               return x + 1;
           }
       }

       public void M()
       {
           int arg = 1;
           (<>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Func<int, int>(<>c.<>9.<M>b__0_0)))(arg);
       }
   }
   ```

   Here, there are still two allocations, one for the generated class (note there's a static field in the class which creates an instance of the class) and another allocation for the `Func<int>` delegate.

As far as I can see, in both cases the compiler generates a class and there are two allocations.
The only difference I can see is that in the first case, the generated class has a member:

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int i;
```

This does increase the allocation size, because the generated class occupies more memory than in the 2nd case.

Did I understand it correctly, is this what the author refers to?

Comment: "Yes" is a boring answer.  Terminology is a bit off, the service/i variable needs to be *captured*, passing it as an argument avoids that.  It is a micro-optimization, you'll never notice the difference in async code.

Comment: @HansPassant I think any answer will do, I just want to be sure my reasoning is correct. Any extra info might help too. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant I understand the "capturing" idea. But if my reasoning is correct, this "capturing" does mean more allocation. And I guess that's what the author means.

Comment: Method arguments also require allocation.  But the captured one is stored on the GC heap, the argument on the stack or processor register.  Still a micro-optimization, you'd have to very unlucky to get it promoted to gen#2 and nobody can debug the kind of code where you'd get more than a kilobyte of it.  Best to make it style preference, I never liked those dangling arguments all that much.

Comment: When I said "allocation" I referred to heap allocation. Stack allocation still takes place, of course, since it involves calling methods. But AFAIK we don't care much about stack allocation, but the heap allocation which is very very expensive compared to stack allocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in caching.

In your original code, a new delegate instance is created on *every* call to `M()`. In the "clever" version, only a single instance is every created, and stored in the static variable.

So if you only call `M()` once, the same number of objects will be allocated. If you call `M()` a million times, you'll have far more objects allocated with the first code than with the second.

This code:

```
(<>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Func<int, int>(<>c.<>9.<M>b__0_0)))(arg);
```

... should be read as effectively:

```
if (cachedDelegate == null)
{
    cachedDelegate = new Func<int, int>(GeneratedClass.CachedInstance.Method);
}
cachedDelegate.Invoke(arg);
```

The instance of `<>c` is also cached (referred to above as `GeneratedClass.CachedInstance`) - only a single instance of that is created. (Although that's less important here, as it only needs to be created when the delegate is created... I'm not sure under what circumstances that compiler optimization is particularly useful.)